# CGAL renderer based on btIDebugDraw (with out QT)?

Tags: c++, rendering, bullet, cgal

Is there a collection of complex structures/renderers (like Nef Polyhedra and Polyhedron - would be all for me) and a simple renderer (engine) that would work alike [bullet `btIDebugDraw` one - virtual class](http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtIDebugDraw.html) - you implement fiew rendering functions, provide instance of that rendering engine object to structures renderers (in bullet case [World like `btDiscreteDynamicsWorld`](http://www.continuousphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtDiscreteDynamicsWorld.html#ae28ddad438d95e1da0fe25d1df41dade) ) here it would be Nef Polyhedra or Polyhedron renderers. Are there such classes in CGAL? Or how using say ready implementation of `btIDebugDraw` render Polyhedron (`CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>`) and Nef Polyhedra (`CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel>`)?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing directly part of the API, but CGAL ships with demos to showcase the functionality and are often used to develop or debug. They are more or less ad-hoc code to render structures with OpenGL using [qglViewer](http://www.libqglviewer.com/). For you the demo that comes with Polyhedron should contain code that shows how to render the specific structures, especially `Scene_nef_polyhedron_item.{h,cpp}` and `Scene_polyhedron_item.{h,cpp}` shoud have what you are looking for.

I cannot comment as how that compares with the other API's you mention as I'm not familiar with them.

In general, drawing Polyhedra with the fixed function pipe-line isn't too hard, but becomes trickier with vertex buffer objects.